# Backup MySQL database from client host using CMD

Tags: c#, mysql, mysql-backup

I have two windows PC name like A,B it have peer to peer connection pc A have installed MySQL 5.6 and I need to take backup database from A (server ip192.168.1.2) to B (client) using CMD I try this code but getting empty file size I'm newbie to MySQL thank you.

```cs
string fileName = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-HHmm");
  
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";

startInfo.Arguments = "/C mysqldump -h 192.168.1.2 -p 3306 -u root -p1234 sms > d:/backup/" + fileName + ".sql";
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

Comment: Is the mysqldump command know to the OS through the PATH environment variable or do you run this code in the folder where the mysqldump is stored?

Comment: I tried to set  path on environment variable but same result can you mention any example, I need to store mysqldump on my client pc thank you

Comment: Another advice, remove the /C and put a /K then comment out the line that hides the output window. You should be able to see if there are errors in your command arguments

Comment: also put the .exe after mysqldump

Comment: Did you try to run command in cmd window? Is it works or failed?

Comment: thank you very much Steve for your quick response its working problem is on the variable PATH